# Task executor in Java that returns first ending task

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to implement something that would get a collection of workers (callables), run it in parallel on a threadpool and when the fastest worker returns a result gracefully shutdown (ExecutorService.shutdownNow) other workers in order not to waste any more resources. If all of the workers finish with exceptions I need to rethrow the most important one (all exceptions thrown by workers are associated with an `importance` value). Also I need to have a timeout on the whole executor that would terminate all workers if they run for too long.

I have thought about using RxJava for that because it feels like a concise and nice solution would be possible to be achieved here. But maybe you can come up with some better tools for that (CompletableFutures, ForkJoinTasks?). Here is a code that I have written already but it's far from being a working solution (I'm not really experienced with reactive programming and thus really struggling with this):

```
public T run(Collection<? extends Worker<T>> workers, long timeout) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workers.size());
    return Observable.from(workers)
            .timeout(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executorService))
            .map(worker -> {
                try {
                    T res = worker.call();
                    executorService.shutdownNow();
                    return res;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
                }
            }).doOnError(Exceptions::propagate).toBlocking().first();
```

I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Are you aware that the "fastest" may not be the one which takes the least amount of time to complete? This depends entirely on the scheduling. So, what is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: You're new here so I won't down vote this. It seems you're asking the group to build a full-feature executor service that could take hundreds/thousands of lines of code. I really don't think you've thought this through. You will never get the features you want in a few lambdas.

Comment: @edharned it is about 15 lines of code and the author posted we he had achieved so far. quite a nice technical challenge, which I have nearly completed. It is up to you to up or down vote, but your judgement is incorrect

Comment: @Oleg Sklyar OK, looks like you're solution holds water.

Comment: @fge of course as fastest I was thinking about the one that takes the least amount of time to complete.

Comment: @edharned as you see there are 2 nice and short solutions. This isn't really a complex thing. I must say I was a bit surprised that I couldn't find anything close to this thing already done on the internet.

Comment: @Paweł Koniarski I am thoroughly chastised. I still have difficulty with streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite an interesting technical challenge, so thanks for asking. Here is a solution using `CompletableFuture` for Java8. In Java7 you could use `io.netty.util.concurrent.Promise` in exactly the same way.

The easiest part is to handle the normal case:

- create a completable future
- schedule tasks
- return the future
- the first to complete completes the future, others are ignored (if not killed then the atomic boolean controls they do not override the value)
- shutdown executor service in the next stage of the future

The trickier part is to complete exceptionally when each single one throws keeping the same logical flow. This is solved by accumulating all the exceptions and completing the future exceptionally when the count reaches the job count in that last failing job. The exception passed on is the first in the list sorted by the rank (here it will be smallest rank, change correspondingly). The exception will be available upon calling `future.get()` and wrapped into an `ExecutionException`.

Finally, because you are getting a future back, you can pass the timeout value into the `get` method.

So here is the actual working solution, the exception class and the tests follow below:

```
public <R> CompletableFuture<R> execute(Collection<? extends Callable<R>> jobs) {
  final CompletableFuture<R> result = new CompletableFuture<>();
  if (jobs == null || jobs.isEmpty()) {
    result.completeExceptionally(new IllegalArgumentException("there must be at least one job"));
    return result;
  }
  final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(jobs.size());

  // accumulate all exceptions to rank later (only if all throw)
  final List<RankedException> exceptions = Collections.synchronizedList(Lists.newArrayList());
  final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  for (Callable<R> job: jobs) {
    service.execute(() -> {
      try {
        // this is where the actual work is done
        R res = job.call();
        // set result if still unset
        if (done.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
          // complete the future, move to service shutdown
          result.complete(res);
        }
      // beware of catching Exception, change to your own checked type
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof RankedException) {
          exceptions.add((RankedException) ex);
        } else {
          exceptions.add(new RankedException(ex));
        }
        if (exceptions.size() >= jobs.size()) {
          // the last to throw and only if all have thrown will run:
          Collections.sort(exceptions, (left, right) -> Integer.compare(left.rank, right.rank));
          // complete the future, move to service shutdown
          result.completeExceptionally(exceptions.get(0));
        }
      }
    });
  }
  // shutdown also on error, do not wait for this stage
  result.whenCompleteAsync((action, t) -> service.shutdownNow());
  return result;
}
```

The `RankedExeption`:

```
public static class RankedException extends Exception {
  private final int rank;

  public RankedException(Throwable t) {
    this(0, t);
  }

  public RankedException(int rank, Throwable t) {
    super(t);
    this.rank = rank;
  }
}
```

And now two tests, success and failure cases (a bit simplified, but still):

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

private static class TestJob implements Callable<Double> {
  private final int index;
  private final int failOnCount;

  TestJob(int index, int failOnCount) {
    this.index = index;
    this.failOnCount = failOnCount;
  }

  @Override
  public Double call() throws RankedException {
    double res = 0;
    int count = (int) (Math.random() * 1e6) + 1;
    if (count > failOnCount) {
      throw new RankedException(count, new RuntimeException("job " + index + " failed"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      res += Math.random();
    }
    return res;
  }
}

@Test
public void test_success() throws Exception {
  List<TestJob> jobs = Lists.newArrayList();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    jobs.add(new TestJob(i, (int)(5*1e5))); // 50% should be alright
  }
  CompletableFuture<Double> res = execute(jobs);
  logger.info("SUCCESS-TEST completed with " + res.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
}

@Test
public void test_failure() throws Exception {
  List<TestJob> jobs = Lists.newArrayList();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    jobs.add(new TestJob(i, 0)); // all should fail
  }
  CompletableFuture<Double> res = execute(jobs);
  exception.expect(ExecutionException.class);
  try {
    res.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
    logger.severe(String.format("FAIL-TEST rank: %s", ((RankedException) ex.getCause()).rank));
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Finally the truncated output of the test runs:

> INFO: SUCCESS-TEST completed with 115863.20802680103
>
> SEVERE: FAIL-TEST rank: 388150
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

**Note**: you might want further signalling via `AtomicBoolean` to actually signal all threads to terminate when first is ready

I do not guarantee the above code is free of errors as it is done in a rush and tests are rudimentary. It is intended to indicate the direction of further digging.

Comment: Nicely done. Every line is self-explainatory and the code works great according to the tests I have done so far. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've done my best to make sure it is correct, so you are most welcome. It is an interesting problem, so it's been a pleasure to tackle it.

Comment: Instead of collecting exceptions in a `Collection` you may want to suppress them into a single `Throwable` instance and check the size of `.getSuppressed()`; if the size is equal to the number of jobs then all jobs have failed and you throw the exception.

Comment: @fge Thanks for the hint, good to learn something new. Given the author wants the highest ranked exception I still feel a collection or a counter along with the highest ranked exception so far are a better choice for this particular problem, but generally you make a good point.

Comment: I have came back to this topic. I think that this `done` flag is not really needed here. Once you `complete` the `CompletableFuture` next `complete` calls don't have any effect.

Comment: @PawełKoniarski This is what the JavaDoc says and this is how I would prefer it to be. In tests however (I think) I have seen other behaviours. Again, I think I have, I am not sure by now. As there is still time to complete before the executor service is shut down (I think) I have seen the result overwritten from another thread. Do test it yourself, set the loop size to e.g. 1e8, remove the atomic check and add a log for the value set and the value returned finally (but you also need to log who set and who returned the value).

Answer (score 2):

Perfect application for RxJava. To get parallel operation use `flatMap` with `subscribeOn` inside the `flatMap`. To pick up errors use `materialize` and to stop as soon as a value is returned successfully use `takeUntil`. Use `timeout` operator for your timeout requirement.

```
ExecutorService executorService =
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workers.size());
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(executorService);
return Observable
    .from(workers)
    .flatMap(worker -> 
         Observable.fromCallable(worker)
             .subscribeOn(scheduler)
             .materialize())
    .takeUntil(notification -> notification.hasValue())
    .toList() 
    .timeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .flatMap(
        list -> {
            Notification<T> last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
            if (last.hasValue()) 
                return Observable.just(last.getValue());
            else {
                // TODO get the error notification from the list 
                // with the highest importance and emit
                return Observable.<T>error(err);
            }
        }).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Comment: I really like this solution. I have replaced `.subscribe(subscriber)` with `.toBlocking().single()` to get the result. Unfortunately, there's a bit of performance drop compared to, for instance, @OlegSklyar solution. For workers that take (in order) 1200, 100, 600ms it takes over 500ms for this one to return whereas it takes less than 300ms using the other solution. Have you got any idea where that could come from?

Comment: I am also not sure that other workers are cancelled after the first one completes. Are they? Would adding `.doAfterTerminate(executorService::shutdownNow)` work?

Comment: Re cancellation, no more work (workers is not really the right term here to be honest) will be scheduled as soon as a value is returned but with either this answer or the `CompletableFuture` answer all work that is currently scheduled will continue regardless. If you want more control of that then you need to make the work fine grained (make it an Observable and regularly check for unsubscription).

Comment: Re the time taken, that's a curious one. What is the work that is being done? If it is cpu intensive then you should be using `Schedulers.computation` because it will have a thread pool equal in size to the number of available processors. That way you won't have overhead of thread creation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the RxJava [AMB](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#amb(java.lang.Iterable)) operator? You need to verify that it completes on the first onComplete, however, as the documentation doesn't say anything about that.

Comment: The problem here is that it works not only on the first onComplete but also on the first onError. I think it wouldn't really be easy to make it work.